# A time series dataset with temperature, humidity and so on without missing values

Tags: dataset, cluster-analysis, temperature

I need a dataset made of time series with multivariate values, containing temperatures and humidities and, eventually, other data, where it's possible perform clustering. Because of the architecture I have to use, I need a dataset without missing values. In other words, I need a dataset similar to the Intel Berkeley Lab dataset buth without missing values.

Do you know some dataset with these characteristics? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a dataset for this purpose: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Appliances+energy+prediction